# Why does Win10 appear to reboot after overnight sleep, and how to stop this behavior?

Tags: windows-10, laptop, sleep, reboot, boot-camp

Running Win10 on a Macbook Pro 2018 via Boot Camp. When I leave my laptop plugged in to sleep overnight, I don't have to hit the power button to turn it back on, however the Windows boot logo appears and I find all apps have closed as if it had just powered on.

Searching around forums, some mentioned it may be the UpdateOrchestrator's doing, but in Task Scheduler, in UpdateOrchestrator, the Reboot_AC and Reboot_Battery tasks are already set to Disabled.

[Elsewhere someone mentioned](https://www.tenforums.com/performance-maintenance/22019-system-turns-off-night-while-sleep-mode-2.html?s=d13fea60d024d8a3ab370c184da3b114) it may be due to the PCIe Link State Power Management settings, however in the description of those settings [here](https://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/292971-pcie-link-state-power-management-turn-off-windows.html) there isn't any setting that would cause a sleeping pc to power all the way off while plugged in.

Any ideas what may be causing this behavior while my laptop is asleep? I'd like for everything to stay exactly as I left it when it was put to sleep. I'm not sure if it's an issue with the Windows OS or the Apple hardware, so apologies if this pans out to being off-topic.

---

**Update feb 6**

The only change that occurred based on the report from running the wizard at Settings - Update and Security - Troubleshoot - Power:

```
Time before computer goes to sleep is too long: Fixed
Restore the default sleep setting for the computer: Completed
```

I also ran `powercfg /SYSTEMSLEEPDIAGNOSTICS`and below is a screenshot of the last recorded sleep session from yesterday, a little after I left work (the next recorded sleep session happened today, this afternoon thus is not relevant).

[image]

---

**Update feb 7**

This morning I ran `powercfg /sleepstudy` and noticed noticed some "abnormal shutdowns" during the night that my laptop booted up on wake:

[image]

~18:25 is when I left work. 9:59 is when I returned.
Details:

[image]

It looks like my computer is crashing when it tries to wake up from sleep. I'm pretty sure the `1% of battery` in the Energy Change column is delta change not total energy at that time, as it was plugged in all night. I will look into how to uncover crash logs if they exist and edit the post again with findings.

Comment: There is a power troubleshooter in Control Panel. _Settings - Update and Security - Troubleshoot - Power_. You can also use at the command prompt `powercfg /?` eg `powercfg /systemsleepdiagnostic`.

Comment: Thanks for that tip. Results: "Time before computer goes to sleep is too long: Fixed ... Restore the default sleep setting for the computer: Completed". That's it unfortunately.

Comment: Edit your question with the results that you got from each. And note `powercfg` has lots of reports and diagnostics (both).

Comment: Done! /////////

Comment: Have you unplugged all peripherals such as your mouse, keyboard, etc and see if it still reboots? It clearly says that it detected **user input**.   I have a PC that wakes up in the middle of the night from complete shutdown...by itself. Might be related. xD

Comment: No I haven't, I'll try that tonight. I have 2 external monitors and a keyboard and mouse plugged in. It says idle time began at 18:30, but then idle time was reset at 18:29 (1 min prior)... presumably that's the last time I gave user input, then shut the lid 1 minute later to put it to sleep. Regardless, I don't care if user input wakes it up. I just don't want it to *shut down* (or do whatever it currently does that *acts* like a fresh reboot on wake-up).

Comment: FYI _NT Status 0xC0000411 (-1073740783)
 = Windows Error 0x290 (656) **NT Status Message**: The system has failed to hibernate (The error code is %hs). Hibernation will be disabled until the system is restarted. 
**Windows Error Message:** The system has failed to hibernate (The error code is %hs). Hibernation will be disabled until the system is restarted._